# How To Setup Local Tunnel Through Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, ssh, remote-desktop, rdp, tunnel

My local machine is using MacOSX/linux and am able to connect to a Windows Remote Desktop machine (using Windows Remote Desktop/Remote Desktop Connection).

The Windows Remote Desktop machine is able to connect to certain servers that I cannot connect to locally on my MAC.  For example, connection to database servers, specific web servers, etc.

How can I setup some kind of tunnel so that I can access the servers locally on my mac?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure port forwarding on the Windows machine

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3390 listenaddress=192.168.1.111 connectport=3389 connectaddress=192.168.0.33
```

where 192.168.1.111 is IP of your Windows machine and 192.168.0.33 is destination server. From your Mac you will connect to Windows machine specifying port in RDP connection 192.168.1.111:3390 and you will be connected to the remote server. You have to provide credentials from the server, not your local Win machine. This configuration survive restarting Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Is there any alternative if I'm not the administrator of the Windows machine?  Looks like it won't let me run the netsh command.

Comment: Don't you have Run as Administrator in context menu for cmd? Another option is to fake that your mac is the windows machine, by switching IP addressess, cloning MAC address - depends on how the access to remote servers is made.

Answer (score 0):

Just install Igiko on your windows machine and then open it in web browser on your MacOSX. Igiko is acting like web-based RDP gateway, using it you will be able to open RDP console to any Windows machine in your network.